# $U(1)$ beta function of low energy effective Seiberg-Witten theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, renormalization

My question is about figure3 (page 8) of this paper 
[hep-th/9705131](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9705131).
Start from Seiberg-Witten theory, integrate out the charged
high energy modes down to Higgs scale and we get a $U(1)$ gauge
theory without matter. Then the author claims that the beta 
function is zero.

Is there any argument or calculation for this?

It seems contradict with formula (2.7) Arkani-Hamed and Murayama ([hep-th/9707133](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9707133)).
$$\frac{1}{g^2_{eff}}= \frac{1}{g^2_{h}}+\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\log{\frac{v^2}{M^2}}+\rm{non-pertubative} $$

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is consistent with page 37 of [this](https://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/theoreticalphysics/Public/MSc/Dissertations/2012/Nick%20Hunter-Jones%20Dissertation.pdf) and page 11 of [this](http://www.physics.uc.edu/~argyres/661/trilec.pdf). The $\beta$-function of $U(1)$ depends on the charge of the degrees of freedom, but since there are none below the scale $a$, it is zero. As for [hep-th/9707133](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9707133v1.pdf), I suppose that the coupling there is given for non-vanishing charges.